# ndk build with Visual studio files

Tags: stl, android-ndk

I am building an android app using the native classes. The problem is that there are some cpp files calling OpenCV and the opencv header files calling VC includes that are not provided in jni. So what should I do? create a new opencv folder and change every opencv files there to right paths? or any other ways to config it? because I don't want to change the original opencv folder. that's for VC programming.

Comment: Can you post an example of an opencv header file that has this problem?

Comment: For example #include <alogrithm>

Comment: anyone knows this? even I include it, the GCC doesn't realize the <> thing in include path

Comment: To _#include_ `<algorithm>` in particular and STL in general you need to work with C++, and use **g++** compiler, not **gcc**.

Comment: I did change to #include "<VC include path>/algorithm" for example. but still various of errors. the out put show that Compile ++.

Comment: No you cannot use VC includes for GCC.

Answer (score 1):

`<algorithm>` is one of the STL headers. You should enable STL support in NDK, as described in  [docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html](http://gitorious.org/mingw-android-ndk/mingw-android-ndk/blobs/e144b4a3d50f8182805424186d9ccba3e7466391/docs/CPLUSPLUS-SUPPORT.html) document.

Comment: I did add 'LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_STL := stlport_static
STLPORT_FORCE_REBUILD := true' to android.mk, but still cannot include <algorithm> or <iostream>. When I change to "<VC include path>/algorithm"  it generate many errors related to some variables in those file vector,iostream ...

Comment: You probably mean that Eclipse does not recognize the headers? Which version of Eclipse and ADT plugin are you using? Because, when I look into `android-ndk-r8b/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport` I find both `algorithm` and `iostream`. And `ndk-build` compiles my test program without a scream.

Comment: what are set in your Android.mk for your test. my make file is : ` LOCAL_MODULE    := testcpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := "C:\OpenCV2.1\lib\cxcore210.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.1\lib\highgui210.lib" "C:\OpenCV2.1\lib\cvaux210.lib" "C:\taucs_full\lib\win32\libtaucs.lib"
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions
APP_STL := stlport_static
STLPORT_FORCE_REBUILD := true` and I cannot include them

Answer (score 1):

pointed out the thing. I need to put those to Application.mk. Thought this file is optional.

Comment: You don't really need Application.mk, these settings you can simply put on the command line: **ndk-build  APP_STL=stlport_static**